useState of props get undefined in React
My User data include one id,userName and one password.
I am trying to send the data I have as an Object array.It goes one by one with .map annotation, but I want to send it as a whole array. Is this possible?  Coming in json format from my database. I want to send my objects as an array to the User Table file. It goes undefined. How can an object array be sent as props?
function User() {


    const [userList,setUserList] = useState([])
    const [error,setError] = useState(null);

    const getAllUsers = async() =>{ 
        const a = await axios.get(BASE_URL + "/users/all")
        
        setUserList(a.data);
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        getAllUsers()
        .then(()=>{
            console.log("Users Promise")
        })
        return(
          <div>
            {<UserTable data = {userList} />}
          </div>
        )
      }
   

UserTable.jsx

function UserTable({props}) {
  debugger
const {id,userName,password} = props;  // It comes undefined here.
    
  console.log(props)
}


This is not a good question. Not much effort went into research before asking.

You're looking for a prop called props:
function UserTable({props}) {
  const {id,userName,password} = props;
  //...
}

But you're passing a prop called data:
<UserTable data = {userList} />

The names need to match.  For example:
function UserTable({data}) {
  const {id,userName,password} = data;
  //...
}


Additionally... The prop you're passing is an array:
useState([])

Arrays do not have properties called id or userName or password.  If the individual objects in that array have those properties then you'd be looking to use those individual objects.
How you use them is not really indicated in the question.  But overall the point is that an array of objects is different from an object, much in the same way that a basket of apples is not an apple.
For example, if you wanted to display these values, you could .map() over them:
function UserTable({data}) {
  const {id,userName,password} = data;
  return (<>
    {data.map(({id,userName,password}) => (
      <div>
        {id}<br/>
        {userName}<br/>
        <em>showing passwords is a bad idea, they shouldn't even be stored in plain text in the first place</em>
      </div>
    ))}
  </>);
}


When the User Table component runs, I sometimes see two arrays on the console. What is the reason for this? The first one appears empty.

@burak: You're initially seeing an empty array because the initial state value is an empty array.  You later see an array with values in it because your AJAX operation updates state to an array with values in it.

I do not fully understand. When performing a get operation with axios, the process is already expected to be completed. When the UserTable component is called, doesn't it pass a full array of props?

@burak: The "A" in "AJAX" stands for "asynchronous".  That AJAX request is a non-blocking operation.  (Even if it were blocking, it doesn't start until the first render is complete anyway.)  First the component renders with the initial state value(s).  Then, at a later time, if you update your state value(s) then the component will re-render with the new values.  The AJAX result updates state at a later time (which may be very fast, but still later).
